# Xamarin Forms How to add for custom layout scrollbar?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have faced with issue how to add `ScrollBar` for Custom Layout ?

Unfortunately I have not found example or any mention in official documentation how to do this ...

I have found only that `CollectionView` has support scrolling and by inheriting from this Layout seems like it possible to do ...

But is there another way ?

Comment: use a ScrollView

Comment: @Jason I cannot because I have implemented custom dynamic grid layout that has some animation for items ... ScrollView do not allow me control TouchEffects

Comment: given that you haven't provided any code or detailed description of what you're doing, it's difficult to answer your question

Comment: @Jason Here is the part of the question https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/183067/scroll-scrollview-programatically-based-on-toucheffect#latest ... But it is not possible to provide the code, it is too big

Comment: What is your custom layout looks like? I think use a scrollview would be a better solution and you should find a way to solve the TouchEffects problem.